# How to explicitely add npm modules by string name to a Vue/Webpack build?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Is it possible to add NPM packages to a Vue build explicitly by string name, and then dynamically import these packages later? Here's what I have, which does not work:

.env

```
VUE_APP_ADDINS=my-package1,my-package2
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.VUE_APP_ADDINS) {
      config.entry('app').merge(process.env.VUE_APP_ADDINS.split(',').map(a => require.resolve(a)));
    }
  },
};
```

Running `vue inspect` gives me a config with an entry as I expect:

```
...
entry: {
    app: [
      './src/main.ts',
      'C:/path/to/my-package1/dist/index.js',
      'C:/path/to/my-package2/dist/index.js'
    ]
  },
...
```

but, clearly I don't understand Webpack enough, as I do not see the code from `my-package` in the bundled output from Vue/Webpack.

Of course then importing doesn't work, but here's what I'd like to be able to do in the Vuex store:

```
await Promise.all(
  process.env.VUE_APP_ADDINS.split(',').map(async (addinName) => 
    import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ addinName)));
```

This of course throws an error: `Error resolving module specifier “my-package1” Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`

Edit:
I got the end result I'd like by adding the following to the top of vue.config.js:

```
const addins = process.env.VUE_APP_ADDINS.split(',');

const addinCode = addins.map((a, i) => `import addin${i} from '${a}';`).join('\n') +
  '\n\nexport default [' +
  addins.map((a, i) => `addin${i}`).join(', ') +
  '];';

  writeFileSync(__dirname + '/src/store/addins.ts', addinCode);
```

When Webpack runs it now includes the addins in its build. This is an ok solution for me, but I'd still like to understand how to do this without programatically writing code files, if it's possible.

Comment: Packages get added to the build when they're `import`ed. You don't need/want to add them as entry points (that wouldn't do what you're thinking). The dynamic import you're doing alone (without the `webpackIgnore` comment) should already be bundling your packages. What's the issue?

Comment: @tony19 I tried removing the `webpackIgnore` and my vue.config.js code, but the package modules still do not show up in the Vue output. I'm not sure how Webpack would know which npm modules to include based on that dynamic import. According to the docs, "It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as import(foo)." (https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import).